# I need help decoding (what I believe) is a base64 encoded message

Tags: encoding, base64

I was given a encoded message as a challenge, and I am completely lost. Sorry if the answer to this is extremely obvious, but I cannot figure out what this code is supposed to represent. The code is:

`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====`

I believe it is base64 because of the `=` trailing at the end, but when converting it to ASCII, I get a bunch of nothing (making me think it is something else). I am not really asking for a direct answer to what the string is, but rather where I can go from here. I have already tried converting the binary value to jpg, but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated! (I also noticed it repeated JV*E a lot, I do not know whether that is significant or not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more likely [base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) than base64, since there are no lower case letters, `1`s, `8`s, `9`s, `+`s, or `/`s. Decoding it as base32 produces:

`MDExMDEwMDAgMDExMTAxMDAgMDExMTAxMDAgMDExMTAwMDAgMDExMTAwMTEgMDAxMTEwMTAgMDAxMDExMTEgMDAxMDExMTEgMDExMTAxMTEgMDExMTAxMTEgMDExMTAxMTEgMDAxMDExMTAgMDExMTEwMDEgMDExMDExMTEgMDExMTAxMDEgMDExMTAxMDAgMDExMTAxMDEgMDExMDAwMTAgMDExMDAxMDEgMDAxMDExMTAgMDExMDAwMTEgMDExMDExMTEgMDExMDExMDEgMDAxMDExMTEgMDExMTAxMTEgMDExMDAwMDEgMDExMTAxMDAgMDExMDAwMTEgMDExMDEwMDAgMDAxMTExMTEgMDExMTAxMTAgMDAxMTExMDEgMDExMDExMTEgMDEwMDEwMDAgMDExMDAxMTEgMDAxMTAxMDEgMDEwMTAwMTEgMDEwMDEwMTAgMDEwMTEwMDEgMDEwMTAwMTAgMDEwMDEwMDAgMDEwMDAwMDEgMDAxMTAwMDA=`

Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! After decoding it with base32, I decoded it with base64 (because now it had lowercase), and I got my answer! (I got rick roll'd, but it is ok)